# How to add fonts to chrome extension properly?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webfonts, manifest.json

Fonts are not visible for my custom script chrome extension.

Folder structure:

```
assets
-fonts
content-app
manifest.json
```

manifest.json:

```
(...)
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": false,
      "js": ["/content-app/runtime.js", "/content-app/polyfills.js", "/content-app/styles.js", "/content-app/main.js"],
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "assets/fonts/icons.ttf",
    "assets/fonts/icons.eot",
    "assets/fonts/icons.svg",
    "assets/fonts/icons.woff"
  ],
```

scss:

```
    $icomoon-font-family: 'icons' !default;
    $icon-equalizer: '\e912'; 

        @font-face {
          font-family: '#{$icomoon-font-family}';
          src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/#{$icomoon-font-family}.eot?64agaf');
          src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/#{$icomoon-font-family}.eot?64agaf#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/#{$icomoon-font-family}.ttf?64agaf') format('truetype'),
            url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/#{$icomoon-font-family}.woff') format('woff'),
            url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/#{$icomoon-font-family}.svg?64agaf##{$icomoon-font-family}') format('svg')
              format('svg');
          font-weight: normal;
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: block;
        }
        
        [class^='icon-'],
        [class*=' icon-'] {
          font-family: '#{$icomoon-font-family}' !important;
          speak: never;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-variant: normal;
          text-transform: none;
          line-height: 1;
        
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        }

.icon-equalizer {
  &:before {
    content: $icon-equalizer;
  }
}
```

If I open chrome url with: chrome-extension://xxxxx/assets/fonts/icons.ttf, the file will be downloaded properly so it seems ok, but when I add some code to my content script like:

```
<span class="icon-equalizer"></span>
```

then nothing happens (I can see '' only). Any idea?

Because of many reasons I use shadow-root, and you can find the code from that element:

```
#shadow-root
<style>
@font-face{font-family:"icons";src:url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/icons.eot?64agaf");src:url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/icons.eot?64agaf#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/icons.ttf?64agaf") format("truetype"),url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/icons.woff") format("woff"),url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/icons.svg?64agaf#icons") format("svg") format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-display:block}[class^='icon-'],[class*=' icon-']{font-family:"icons" !important;speak:never;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-variant:normal;text-transform:none;line-height:1;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.icon-equalizer:before{content:""}
(...)
</style>
```

Comment: There should be some answers for this exact task (one I remember suggested using data URI), but I'd like to suggest a possibly better solution: put all of your UI into an iframe (only its html file should be exposed in web_accessible_resources) and load all the resources inside just like you would do on any normal page. This way your fonts won't interfere with the web page.

Comment: wOxxOm: Yes I saw them but, I think my issue is different (I can't see any errors etc) Because of many problems with overriding css, I decided to use shadow-root, I'm not using iframe  (had problems with iframes too)

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated the code above with shadow-root, maybe it helps